# How to access or generate a signed Rails Session Cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

The Rails response has a Set-Cookie header.

It seems that this is set in the ActionDispatch::Cookies middleware.

How to get or generate a Set-Cookie header?

Rails 7

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html